# Why arduino mega serial monitor doesn't display anything in the serial monitor?

Tags: arduino, serial-communication

I can't seem to create a serial communication between esp866 nodemcuv3 and arduino mega 2560. The code seems to be working with only text messages. However, when the lcd, motor and temperature sensor is added the code doesn't seem to be working. Code is given below.

```
WORKING CODE:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); //rx,tx
void setup(){
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
}

void loop (){
  if(mySerial.available() >= 2) {
    int data = mySerial.read();
    data = (data << 8) + mySerial.read();
    if (data == 0){
      Serial.println("BREWING: Light COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);
       mySerial.write("reset");
    } else if (data == 1) {
      Serial.println("BREWING: Normal COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);
       mySerial.write("reset");
    }else if (data == 2) {
      Serial.println("BREWING: Strong COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);
       mySerial.write("reset");
  }
}
}


CODE THAT DOESN'T WORK:
#include <SoftwareSerial.h>
#include <Wire.h>
#include <LiquidCrystal_I2C.h>
#include <OneWire.h>
#include <DallasTemperature.h>

#define ONE_WIRE_BUS 2
OneWire oneWire(ONE_WIRE_BUS);
DallasTemperature sensors(&oneWire);

#define ENA 5   // Enable Pin for Motor A
#define IN1 7   // Input Pin 1 for Motor A
#define IN2 6   // Input Pin 2 for Motor A

SoftwareSerial mySerial(10, 11); //rx,tx
LiquidCrystal_I2C lcd(0x27, 16, 2);

void setup(){
  mySerial.begin(115200);
  Serial.begin(115200);
  
  pinMode(ENA, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(IN2, OUTPUT);

  lcd.begin(20, 21);
  lcd.backlight();
  lcd.setCursor(0, 0);
  lcd.print("Temp: ");

  sensors.begin();
}

void loop(){
  if(mySerial.available() >= 2){
    int data = mySerial.read();
    data = (data << 8) + mySerial.read();
    if (data == 0){
      Serial.println("BREWING: Light COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);
      
      // Read temperature value from the DS18B20
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      float temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

      // print the temperature on the LCD
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(temp);

      // Control the L298N motor
      digitalWrite(IN1, HIGH);
      digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
      delay(1000);
      digitalWrite(IN1, LOW);
      digitalWrite(IN2, LOW);
      analogWrite(ENA, 128);

      mySerial.write("reset");
    } else if (data == 1) {
      Serial.println("BREWING: Normal COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);

      // Read temperature value from the DS18B20
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      float temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

      // print the temperature on the LCD
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(temp);

      mySerial.write("reset");
    } else if (data == 2) {
      Serial.println("BREWING: Strong COFFEE");
      Serial.println(data);

      // Read temperature value from the DS18B20
      sensors.requestTemperatures();
      float temp = sensors.getTempCByIndex(0);

      // print the temperature on the LCD
      lcd.setCursor(0, 1);
      lcd.print(temp);

      mySerial.write("reset");
    }
  }
}
```

I want to be able to completely run the conditions since we want to run a motor using an app which is connected to thingspeak through nodemcu v3 which also sends values (0,1,2) to arduino. However, as I stated earlier the code doesn't work with the added codes for I2C lcd, motor and temp sensor.

Thank you for everyone who will be willing to help.

Comment: use Serial1, not SoftwareSerial. pins are labeled RX1 and TX1 on the Mega.

Comment: Hello the answer is much appreciated. However I was able to make something work such as removing the lcd, motor, and temperature. Instead I created a condition that whenever 0,1,2 each will lit up a LED based on the condition. I just want to know whether the code for lcd, motor and temperature is in wrong place?

Answer (score 0):

Sofware serial doesn't really work well at those rates. Turn it down to 9600 or use hardware serial which the mega has a few of.

https://forum.arduino.cc/t/does-softwareserial-really-work-at-115200-baud/327450